# What is the equivalent of DbSet<TEntity>.Local in the ObjectSet<TEntity>?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to get an entity that has already been loaded into the context. It's a legacy system so I cannot change the context creation (so that I can access it through DbSet) and have to work through ObjectSet API.

What is the best equivalent of DbSet.Local property in the ObjectSet API?

It looks like I could use something like `objectContext.GetObjectByKey(key)` or `objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(key)` but the creation of the EntityKey seems to involve hardcoding type and property names as strings:

```
var key = new EntityKey("MyEntities.Employees", "EmployeeID", 1);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781018.aspx) under `DbSet.Local`.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. Took a look at her book. Looks like GetObjectStateEntries it is.

Comment: Perhaps post that as an answer then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Julie Lerman's blog post linked by Gert and her book (“Programming Entity Framework”) it looks like I'm going with this helper method:

```
public class MyUnitOfWork : MyEntities 
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetLocalObjects<T>() where T : class
    {
        var localObjects = ObjectStateManager
            .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged)
            .Where(e => e.Entity is T)
            .Select(e => e.Entity as T);
        return localObjects;
    }
}
```

And then using it in the following way:

```
_myUnitOfWork.GetLocalObjects<Employee>().First(x => x.EmployeeID == 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or the above as an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Local<T>(this ObjectSet<T> ObjectSet) where T : class
{
   var localObjects = ObjectSet.Context.ObjectStateManager
       .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged)
       .Where(e => e.Entity is T)
       .Select(e => e.Entity as T);
   return localObjects;
}
```

Usage:

```
Row row = Context.MyObjectSet.Where(mos => mos.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();

if (row == null) // no row exists
{
    // see if the row exists in the Entity Cache
    row = Context.MyObjectSet.Local<MyObjectType>().Where(mos => mos.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();

    if (row == null)
    {
        row = new MyObjectType();  // no, so create a new one
        Context.MyObjectSet.AddObject(row);
    }
}
```